# How can I allow user without administrator rights start stop application pool in IIS from cmd

Tags: iis

When I'm running console in elevated mode following command works fine.
appcmd start apppool /apppool.name:MyApp

I need to start\stop app pool from CI, that runs on different user whithout administrator rights. How can I allow this user to start/stop application pool?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with putting command to .bat file, and running it in elevated powershell from cmd.
Command for cmd
powershell -Command "Start-Process C:*****.bat -Verb RunAs"